# How to restrict multiple file selection in PickerView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to load one URL. And that URL will open a registration form, in that we have a provision to picking images and videos from device and upload.
Here it is presenting picker view.

But the problem is we are able to select multiple files at a time. But I want to restrict multiple file selection. How can I restrict of selecting multiple files. (I'm using Swift 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a lot of control over the content from a `WKWebView`. Single or multi selection is more like a server side thing. For example I have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>  
    <input type="file" multiple /> test multi <br/>
    <input type="file" /> test single
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run it on web view, I see this

[image]
[image]
So if you own the site, you really need to make this change to your HTML code, not doing stuff with your webview.

Comment: even without multiple, you can select multiple photos with swipe gesture in ios. However after selection only one image will be selected but it shows that you have selected multiple images. can we restrict that also?

Answer (score 0):

image picker controller & didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo this two method  into fire a logic a minimum 10 pic select